# how to call a function in when button click

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, ag-grid

I am trying to call a **dataUpdate function** when click the **edit() button**

I am trying to update the record

version:

- Angular CLI: 10.0.6
- Angular: 10.0.10

[image]

registration.component.html

```
    <div>
      <button type="button" (click)="registration()">Submit</button>
      <div style="margin:5px;"></div>
      <button type="button" (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
    </div>

<h2>List Of Employee</h2>
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 1150px; height: 200px;"
                 class="ag-theme-balham"
                 [rowData]="elist"
                 [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
                 (rowClicked)='onGridRowClicked($event)'>
</ag-grid-angular>
```

registration.component.ts

```
  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'empid', field: 'empid' },
    { headerName: 'username', field: 'username' },
    { headerName: 'empaddress', field: 'empaddress' },
    { headerName: 'password', field: 'password' },
    { headerName: 'country', field: 'country' },
    {
      headerName: 'Edit',
      
      template: '<span><i class="fa fa-edit" data-action-type="edit"></i></span>',
    }
  ];

  onGridRowClicked(e: any) {
    if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
      let actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type");
      if (actionType == "edit") {

        this.rowData = this.myservice.getExistRecord(e.data.empid).subscribe((data: any) => {
          debugger
          console.log("inside get data from list 1")

          if (data.message == "GetSuccess") {

            //get data from the list
            debugger
            this.txtusername = e.data.username;
            this.txtempaddress = e.data.empaddress;
            this.txtpassword = e.data.password;
            this.txtcountry = e.data.country;

           //after get the data then update a record
           var dataUpdate = function () {
              this.myservice.editExistRecord(e.data.empid, this.txtusername, this.txtempaddress, this.txtpassword, this.txtcountry).subscribe((data: any) => {
                console.log("Inside editExistRecord")
                if (data.message == "UpdateSuccessfully") {
                  this.list();
                }
              });
            }

            console.log("empid", e.data.empid);
            console.log("Edit Icon Clicked");
          }
        });
      }
      else if (actionType == "delete") {
        console.log("View delete action clicked");
      }
    }
  }
 
  edit() {
    console.log("inside edit button click event");
    //dataUpdate();//here I am trying to call dataupdate function
  }
```

```
e.data.empid                 //here I am get the empid that is the reason I create a function
```

how to call this function

```
var dataUpdate = function () {
```

when user press the edit() button then I want to call dataUpdate function?

I get the data from the list but after getting the data I want to update them

If I am writing this code outside then **empid is undefined**

[image]

Comment: dataUpdate and edit() is not in the same scope. You need to declare dataUpdate outside onGridRowClicked

Comment: @argoo as you said then problem is empid is undefined see this console message  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiAev.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refactor your component something like this

```
onGridRowClicked(e: any) {
  if (e.event.target !== undefined) {
    let actionType = e.event.target.getAttribute("data-action-type");
    if (actionType == "edit") {

      this.rowData = this.myservice.getExistRecord(e.data.empid).subscribe((data: any) => {
        debugger
        console.log("inside get data from list 1")

        if (data.message == "GetSuccess") {

          //get data from the list
          debugger
          this.txtusername = e.data.username;
          this.txtempaddress = e.data.empaddress;
          this.txtpassword = e.data.password;
          this.txtcountry = e.data.country;
          this.empId = e.data.empid;
          this.dataUpdate();
          console.log("empid", e.data.empid);
          console.log("Edit Icon Clicked");
        }
      });
    }
    else if (actionType == "delete") {
      console.log("View delete action clicked");
    }
  }
}

//after get the data then update a record
dataUpdate() {
  this.myservice.editExistRecord(this.empId, this.txtusername, this.txtempaddress, this.txtpassword, this.txtcountry).subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log("Inside editExistRecord")
    if (data.message == "UpdateSuccessfully") {
      this.list();
    }
  });
}

edit() {
  this.dataUpdate();
}
```

Comment: yes I am trying this.dataupdate() but give an error ```TS2339 (TS) Property 'dataUpdate' does not exist on type 'RegistrationComponent'.```

Comment: thanks for answer I am facing this error see this console log https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqtaR.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPiR9.png

Comment: I am use put method in my web api

Comment: can you put this on stackblitz. it would be easier to solve that way. I can't see any reason why you would see dataUpdate doesn't exist.

Comment: ensure it is a typescript function, not a javascript plain function

Comment: just add httpclient in stackblitz and you see which place I am doing wrong please help

Comment: i fixed the httpClient issue in stackblitz. but that wont help. 
Do one thing, initially keep the edit button disabled. 
when u select a row and your data is returned from server, then enable the edit button
use a variable `isEditEnabled` and manipulate this variable accordingly.

Comment: when u select a row and your data is returned from server - yes when I click on edit icon then data is return from the server see this console image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jCkK.png

Comment: then mark the flag `isEditEnabled = true`. 
on constructor keep `isEditEnabled = false`
on edit button in html , use 
`<button type="button" (click)="edit()" [disabled]="!isEditEnabled">Edit</button>`

Comment: I am trying to solve this issue last 2 days but not able to solve the problem

Comment: I know what are you thinking without press the edit button give the same error and after press the edit button give the same error https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfd8s.png now I note this thing

Answer (score 0):

for edit formValue you will have to `post` or `put` request on server after patch data from list !

for more info check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-editform)

Comment: can I change here to post instead to put see this service image code https://i.stack.imgur.com/JF7nJ.png currently I am using post can I replace post instead to put

Comment: Yes you can send put request

Comment: yes I am using put method but not solve the issue I am facing 404 error https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqtaR.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPiR9.png can you help more please I am trying to solve this quetion last 2 days

Comment: Backend is on nodeJS ?

Comment: no .net mvc see this image of my web api  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdF8t.png which place need to correction I am calling .net mvc webpai in backendservice.service.ts my web api is working fine still I am not solve this problem